# Create links to n turtles first based on attribute then random

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I have a population of turtles where I would like them to create a random number of links to other turtles based on a 'bias' (a value from 1 to 5) I've given them. Now, if there aren't enough turtles with the same 'bias' then I would like them to first create links with the turtles with the same bias and then create links to random other turtles.

So far I've figured out this much

```
    ask people [ 
      set my_friends 1 + random (average-node-degree * 2)
      create-links-to n-of my_friends other people with [bias = [bias] of myself]
     ]
```

But then I run into the problem that there might not be enough turtles with the same bias as I would like them to create links to. How do make the turtles create links to random turtles with the 'remaining' number of my_friends?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The answer has been improved incorporating JenB's suggestion in the comment.

I would do

```
ask people [ 
  set my_friends 1 + random (average-node-degree * 2)
  let target other people with [bias = [bias] of myself] ; This is just for readability.

  ifelse (my_friends <= count target)
    [create-links-to n-of my_friends target]
    [create-links-to target
     let surplus (my_friends - count target)
     let backup-target people with [bias != [bias] of myself]
     create-links-to up-to-n-of surplus backup-target]
]
```

So just ask turtles to keep track of the spare friends-space they have, and use it to target people that have a different bias than their preferred one.

Comment: This is good but you don't need the second `ifelse` since you can use `up-to-n-of` instead of `n-of` in the second allocation

Comment: @JenB Indeed! I edited my answer including that, thanks.